# Blazor WASM - Build Error - "Static web asset has a conflicting web root path"

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a Blazor WASM app running on .Net Standard 2.1 which has suddenly started showing the following error whenever I try to build the app.

> The static web asset 'C:\MyProject\wwwroot\appsettings.json' has a
> conflicting web root path '/wwwroot/appsettings.json' with the project
> file 'wwwroot\appsettings.json'.

Double-clicking the build error takes me to the following section in the file:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets

```
    <ValidateStaticWebAssetsUniquePaths
      StaticWebAssets="@(_ReferencedStaticWebAssets)"
      WebRootFiles="@(_WebRootFiles)" />
```

I have been developing the app over the last several weeks, and have never had this build error before.

Nothing has changed with regards to the client-side appsettings.json file.

I've tried deleting the bin and obj folders, cleaning the project, and doing a full rebuild - all to no effect.

Some articles I've found (e.g. https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/knowledge-base/static-asset-conflicting-root-path ) suggest deleting the "_content" folder, but I have no such folder.

I've come to a grinding halt.

Does anyone have any suggestions that I might try?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to solve this error without seeing your project and file structure, but one thing you can look for is whether you have an appsettings.json file at the same directory in both Server and Client projects. (For ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor)

Comment: Both the Blazor WASM project and the ASP.NET Core hosted API both have their own appsettings.json files, but they are completely independent.  

Each project only has a single appsettings.json file, so I don't understand where there could be a conflict.  I have another application with a very similar structure (Blazor WASM + ASP.NET Core API) where each have their own appsettings.json, with no issue.  And in any case, I have been developing this offending app over the last couple of months with these 2 appsettings file with no issues - until yesterday.

Comment: By way of investigation, I renamed the client-side appsettings.json to some arbitrary name, just to see if I could get the app to build.  This time, it produced a different, although similar, error, reporting a conflict with the app.css file.

"The static web asset 'C:\MyProject\wwwroot\css\app.css' has a conflicting web root path '/wwwroot/css/app.css' with the project file 'wwwroot\css\app.css'."

So, I temporarily renamed app.css, and tried a build again.  This time got the same error, but relating to \bootstrap.min.css'.

Could there be some sort of cache I need to clear?

Comment: I've now found what the issue was.  I have another Blazor WASM project within the same solution, and for some reason, a project reference had crept in from my problematic Blazor app to this other one, hence the build error with the conflicts.  Makes sense now.  I removed the project reference, and everything is working again.  Thanks for your input. :)

Comment: Glad you could fix your issue!

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this recently. The solution for me was to remove the bootstrap library on the server project. (`wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/`). Basically what you're likely hitting is that the Client project has a file with the same name as a file in the matching directory on the server project. Since they all get packed together and served as static web files, this creates a conflict that needs to be resolved. Deleting either will work.

Comment: better explanation than the accepted answer

Comment: Yep! Thats the correct answer! For me the error was caused by a favicon.ico that exists in both Server and Client projects, both projects had the `wwwroot/favicon.ico`. I just renamed one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have two appsettings.json files and it's causing a build issue. I'd suggest doing a search in your project for appsettings.json and see if there is a duplicate. (Can be in both projects like the answer above.)

Answer (score 0):

To those who may have a similar issue regarding a file/package I just `removed` that file and `build the project`. Then I `put it back` in its location and `rebuild` it.

Maybe doesn't sound so clever but I had the same problem suddenly with no change and this helped me to get rid of it.